# Delete Multiple DB rows and Images with Same title

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to delete multiple rows based on 'slug' column using Codeigniter. Form DB all rows are deleted but the problem is with Images. From the root directory Only the first image is deleted. The the other rows images are not deleting.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function deletePost() {
    $slug = $this->input->post('type');
    $query = $this->db->query("Select * from posts_images where slug='$slug'");
    $img = $query->row_array();
    $imgPath = $img['image_path'];
    if (is_file($imgPath)) {
        foreach ($query as $deletRow) { // This foreach is not working
            unlink($imgPath.$deletRow);
        }
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug)->delete('posts_images');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Posts Deleted Successfully');
        redirect('dashboard/Cproducts/showData', 'refresh');
    }
     else {
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug)->delete('posts_images');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Posts Deleted Successfully');
        redirect('dashboard/Cposts/showData', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Here is the DB screenshot:

[image]

In the above screenshot, the second-row Image is not deleting. I have applied the foreach before deleting the rows from DB, but the foreach is not working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Call the "where" method before the "delete" method.

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('slug', $slug)->delete('posts_images');
```

Comment: Hi @MDM  thank you for your reply. I have tried but still, only the first image is unlinking from root directory. There is no issue with the DB. All rows with the same "slug" are deleted but the problem is with Images I have updated the controller with `foreach` . Could you please have a look, where the problem is now